# PHP Class To Generate Semantic UI Threaded Comments HTML

Tags: php, multithreading, comments, semantic-ui

I've tried to generate [Semantic UI threaded comments HTML](http://semantic-ui.com/views/comment.html#threaded) using PHP class for many hours but unfortunately I couldn't do that.

Here is my current class that didn't work properly:

```
class SemanticUiThreadedComments {

    function PrintComments( $comments ) {

        /** Comment prepare start */
        foreach ( $comments as $k => &$v ) {
            if ( $v['comment_parent'] != 0 ) {
                $comments[ $v['comment_parent'] ]['children'][] =& $v;
            }
        }
        unset( $v );

        foreach ( $comments as $k => $v ) {
            if ( $v['comment_parent'] != 0 ) {
                unset( $comments[ $k ] );
            }
        }

        /** Comment prepare end */

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="ui threaded comments">';
        $html .= '<h3 class="ui dividing header">'.__( 'Comments','trusty' ).'</h3>';

        ob_start();
        $this->PrintSingleComments( $comments );
        $html .= ob_get_clean();

        $html .= $this->reply_form();
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;

    }

    function indent( $size ) {
        $string = '';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
            $string .= '</div>';
        }
        echo $string;
    }

    function PrintSingleComments( $comments, $indent = 0 ) {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
            echo $this->comment( $comment, 1 );
            if ( ! empty( $comment['children'] ) ) {

                $this->PrintSingleComments( $comment['children'], $indent + 1 );

            }
                  $div_num = $indent + 1;
                  $this->indent( $div_num );
        }
    }

    function comment( $comment ) {
        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="comment" id="'.$comment['comment_id'].'">';
        echo $this->avatar();
        echo $this->content();
        echo ( ! empty( $comment['children'] ))? '<div class="comments">':'</div>';

        $html = ob_get_clean();

        return $html;
    }

    function avatar() {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<a class="avatar">';
        $html .= '<img src="/images/avatar/small/matt.jpg">';
        $html .= '</a>';

        return $html;
    }

    function content() {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="content">';
        $html .= '<a class="author">Matt</a>';
        $html .= '<div class="metadata">';
        $html .= '<span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="text">';
        $html .= 'How artistic!';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="actions">';
        $html .= '<a class="reply">Reply</a>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
    }

    function reply_form() {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<form class="ui reply form">';
        $html .= '<div class="field">';
        $html .= '<textarea></textarea>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="ui primary submit labeled icon button">';
        $html .= '<i class="icon edit"></i> Add Reply';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</form>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

---

```
$comments = array(
    1 => array( 'comment_id' => 1, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    2 => array( 'comment_id' => 2, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    3 => array( 'comment_id' => 3, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    5 => array( 'comment_id' => 5, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    11 => array( 'comment_id' => 11, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    17 => array( 'comment_id' => 17, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    23 => array( 'comment_id' => 23, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    28 => array( 'comment_id' => 28, 'comment_parent' => 0, 'children' => array() ),
    4 => array( 'comment_id' => 4, 'comment_parent' => 1, 'children' => array() ),
    6 => array( 'comment_id' => 6, 'comment_parent' => 1, 'children' => array() ),
    8 => array( 'comment_id' => 8, 'comment_parent' => 2, 'children' => array() ),
    9 => array( 'comment_id' => 9, 'comment_parent' => 2, 'children' => array() ),
    7 => array( 'comment_id' => 7, 'comment_parent' => 3, 'children' => array() ),
    12 => array( 'comment_id' => 12, 'comment_parent' => 7, 'children' => array() ),
    13 => array( 'comment_id' => 13, 'comment_parent' => 12, 'children' => array() ),
);

$threaded_comments = new SemanticUiThreadedComments();
echo $threaded_comments->PrintComments( $comments );
```

I don't want any kind of limits, for example, a comment may have ten levels of threaded child comments.

Any suggestions on how to get this class to work or a better way to achieve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the perfect solution to my question and because of that I'll not pick it as an answer, however, this is a working class, I tried to do it in an entirely different method, so I rewirte my class, hope someone can find it useful.

If anyone at anytime post an answer better than this I'll pick it as the answer to my question, we post questions here not just for ourselves but in order to help each other.

```
class Semantic_Ui_Comments_Generator {

    private $comments ;
    private $user_data ;

    function __construct( $comments ) {
        $this->comments = $comments;
    }

    function PrintComments() {

        $rest_of_comments = array();

        $trusty_comments = $this->comments;

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="ui threaded comments">';
        $html .= '<h3 class="ui dividing header">'.__( 'Comments','trusty' ).'</h3>';

        foreach ( $trusty_comments  as $key => $comment ) {

            if (  $comment->comment_parent == 0 ) {
                $html .= $this->comment( $comment );
            } else {
                $rest_of_comments[ $key ] = $comment;
            }
        }

        $html .= $this->reply_form();
        $html .= '</div>';

        $num_rest_of_comments = count( $rest_of_comments );

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_rest_of_comments; $i++ ) {

            if ( empty( $rest_of_comments ) ) {
                break;
            }

            foreach ( $rest_of_comments  as $key => $comment ) {

                libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->loadHTML( $html );

                // get the element you want to append to
                $current_comment = $dom->getElementById( 'comments_of_'.$comment->comment_parent );

                if ( $current_comment ) {

                    // create the fragment
                    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

                    $new_comment = $this->comment( $comment );

                    // add content to fragment
                    $fragment->appendXML( $new_comment );
                    // actually append the element
                    $current_comment->appendChild( $fragment );

                    /*
                    * Clean things up
                    */
                    // remove <!DOCTYPE
                    $dom->removeChild( $dom->doctype );
                    // remove <html><body></body></html>
                    $dom->replaceChild( $dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild );

                    $html = $dom->saveHtml();

                    unset( $rest_of_comments[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        return  $html;
    }

    function comment( $comment ) {

        $this->user_data = get_user_by( 'id', $comment->user_id );

        $html = '<div class="comment" id="comment_'.$comment->comment_id.'">';
        $html .= $this->avatar( $comment->user_id );
        $html .= $this->content( $comment,$this->user_data );
        $html .= $this->has_child( $comment->comment_id )? '<div class="comments" id="comments_of_'.$comment->comment_id.'"></div>':'';
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
    }

    function has_child( $comment_id ) {
         $trusty_comments = $this->comments;

        foreach ( $trusty_comments as $key => $comment ) {
            if ( $comment->comment_parent == $comment_id ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function avatar( $user_id ) {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<a class="avatar">';
        $html .= get_avatar( $user_id ,35 );
        $html .= '</a>';

        return $html;
    }

    function content( $comment, $user_data ) {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="content">';
        $html .= '<a class="author">'.$user_data->user_login.'</a>';
        $html .= '<div class="metadata">';
        $html .= '<span class="date">'.$comment->date.'</span>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="text">';
        $html .= $comment->comment;
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="actions">';
        $html .= '<a class="reply">Reply</a>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
    }

    function reply_form() {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<form class="ui reply form">';
        $html .= '<div class="field">';
        $html .= '<textarea></textarea>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="ui primary submit labeled icon mini button">';
        $html .= '<i class="icon edit"></i> Add Reply';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</form>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Please notice that the comments data that expected to enter to the class is an array of objects, not an associative array like in the question.

It is something like:

```
array(7) {
  [1] =>
  class stdClass#366 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-13 00:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(74) "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2] =>
  class stdClass#365 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "2"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-13 02:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(75) "publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3] =>
  class stdClass#364 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "3"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-13 08:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(132) "centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [5] =>
  class stdClass#363 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "5"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-16 00:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(207) "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6] =>
  class stdClass#362 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "6"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-16 02:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(207) "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing"
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [7] =>
  class stdClass#361 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "7"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-16 04:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(207) "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [8] =>
  class stdClass#360 (7) {
    public $comment_id =>
    string(1) "8"
    public $review_id =>
    string(2) "26"
    public $user_id =>
    string(1) "1"
    public $date =>
    string(19) "2016-07-19 05:00:00"
    public $status =>
    string(7) "pending"
    public $comment =>
    string(139) "containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    public $comment_parent =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```